in macOS Sequoia, where does the new Passwords.app save it's passwords and where are they stored in my TimeMachine backup?
Title says it all. I can remember that previous macOS versions stored them in Keychain.app, but I cannot find the passwords there since the update.
Thanks


Since OS X 10.9, Macs have had one and only one Data Protection keychain for each user. If you share your keychain in iCloud, this is the local copy of that shared keychain and is known as iCloud Keychain; if you don’t share it in iCloud, then it’s known as Local Items instead. The local copy of this is normally stored in ~/Library/Keychains/[UUID]/keychain-2.db, where the UUID is that assigned to that Mac.

Inside Sequoia’s new Passwords app (eclecticlight.co)

Basically, they haven't really changed how they're stored, they just created a new app to manage them.
